# Terraform pass a list for identifiers in an IAM policy Document

Tags: terraform, yaml

We are using Terraform to store secrets inside AWS secrets manager. We would like to expand our Terraform to add resource access policy to each secret to only allow certain IAM roles or user access the secret and get it is value. We are defining each secret and it is metadata using YAML. Terraform will then decode the yaml and store all the contents in a map. We then have a for_each to iterate through each map and create the secrets. Below is the yaml definition for a secret

```
nonprod:
- name: my-super-secret
  metadata:
    description: my-super-secret
  value: somesecret
  policy: true #This is the feature we trying to add. It will tell TF to add resource access policy
  iam_roles:
    - "arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/sagemaker"
    - "arn:aws:iam::account-id:user/jon.doe"
    - "arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/test"
  tags:
    purpose: sagemaker
```

The YAML is decoded and then stored in a `var.secrets` map. Using TF console this is what TF store in var.secrets after decoding YAML.

```
{
    "metadata" = {
      "description" = "my-super-secret"
    }
    "name" = "my-super-secret"
    "policy" = true
    "iam_roles" = [
      "arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/sagemaker",
      "arn:aws:iam::account-id:user/jane.doe",
      "arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/test",
    ]
    "tags" = {
      "purpose" = "sagemkaer"
    }
    "value" = "somesecret"
  }
```

on the `main.tf` file, I added the following code for the IAM policy document:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "example" {
  for_each = { for item in var.secrets : item.name => item }
  statement {
    sid = "EnableAccessFor${each.value.name}"

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [lookup(each.value, "iam_roles")]
    }

    actions = [
      "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
    ]

    resources = [
      "*",
    ]
  }

}
```

then I am passing the policy document to `aws_secretsmanager_secret_policy` resource to attach the policy to the secret that has `policy` set as `true`

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_policy" "policy" {
  depends_on = [aws_secretsmanager_secret.secret]
  for_each = { for item in var.secrets : item.name => item }
  secret_arn = each.key

  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.example.json
}
```

no matter what way I use, I always get errors when I run a plan. I have used the following functions with no luck:

`join`, `concat`, `toset`, `splat`, `jsonencode` and `for expressions`

I get the following errors:

1. using for expression  `identifiers = [for r in lookup(each.value, "iam_roles") : r]` produces this error:  `Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: the given object has no attribute "iam_roles"`
2. using splat `identifiers = "${each.value[*].iam_roles}"` produces this error: `Inappropriate value for attribute "identifiers": element 0: string required.`
3. using `toset` with `lookup` `identifiers = "${toset(lookup(each.value, "iam_roles", ""))}"` produces this error `Invalid value for "v" parameter: cannot convert string to set of any single type.`
4. using `join` with `lookup` `identifiers = ["${join(", ", lookup(each.value, "iam_roles", ""))}"]` produces this error `Invalid value for "lists" parameter: list of string required.`
5. using `jsonencode` `identifiers = [jsonencode(each.value.iam_roles)]` produces this error `This object does not have an attribute named "iam_roles".`
6. using just `each.value` without `lookup` `identifiers = [each.value.iam_roles]` produces this error `Inappropriate value for attribute "identifiers": element 0: string required.`

Any idea?

****Update****

I got rid of the `iam_policy_document` and instead opt-in to use the aws_secretsmanager_secret_policy resource with a json-policy. See example below:

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_policy" "policy" {
  depends_on = [aws_secretsmanager_secret.secret]
  for_each = { for item in var.secrets : item.name => item if try(item.policy, false)}
  secret_arn = aws_secretsmanager_secret.secret[each.key].arn 

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "EnableAccessFor${each.value.name}",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
        "${join(",", formatlist("\"%s\"", each.value.iam_roles))}"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}
```

The part I am having issue is with the `each.value.iam_roles` as that is a tuple vs. a string. I tried multiple ways to convert that into string but it is not working. Perhaps someone can help me with that.

Comment: Why do you need `for_each` here?

Comment: In the policy document data source I mean.

Comment: so it creates a resource policy with the roles specified in the yaml definition of the secret and attaches it to the secret

Comment: So you don't need multiple policies, only one with the multiple IAM roles?

Comment: correct, only one policy with the multiple IAM roles per secret if the consumer of that secret has set `policy` to `true`

Comment: Ok, and `for_each` works as expected for the resource block? I am asking because if that is the case then the variable value you added to the question cannot be used to reproduce the error as validation fails for the `for_each` in the data source for policy.

Comment: "The YAML is decoded and then stored " - how come? The `var.secret` is different then your yaml. Its does not have the same structure (missing `nonprod` attribute). So how exactly do you decode yaml into `var.secret`?

Comment: the yaml files are decoded in a `local.tf` file and stored in map called `local.secrets` when the module is called to create secrets `local.secrets[*]` is passed for `var.secrets` the nonprod attribute is passed dynamically using `var.env` hope that helps.

Comment: posted an update ^

Answer (score 0):

issue was resolved with encoding the entire policy to JSON using the `jsonencode function in Terraform.